# What is the maximum DOD for a Li-Ion Battery?

Tags: batteries, identification, lithium-ion, discharge, undervoltage

I bought these 4.8 AH, 3.7 V - 4.2 V lithium batteries that came without a datasheet and I didn't manage to find it anywhere on the internet. Can someone figure out its maximum safe discharge voltage level? (even if it's an approximation).
extra specs :
short-circuit current: 12 A (measured)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fake specs. For that capacity Isc should be 20A.  measure C=I dt/dV for a constant current over some time in seconds and record the change in V, Then compute mAH

Comment: Usually high capacity batteries like that are essentially fake. My suggestion would be to discharge the battery safely with a resistor and then take it to an appropriate battery disposal or recycling location. Buy batteries with spec sheets from reputable vendors. Even when you do that you may sometimes get fake batteries.

Comment: unfortunately , I am aware that the capacity of these batteries is not as it is stated on their cover , however, I am not very familiar with the techniques used to determine battery specs such as the DOD, one thing is for sure though: their short circuit current is in fact 12 A (I tested it myself ), also , unfortunately due to some circumstances I am unable to buy other batteries from reputable sources.

Comment: Weigh it in gm and compare with another battery and report in Q pls.

Comment: weight it ? are you referring to their physical weight?

Comment: Yes and these are probably 2000mAH 4C cells is my SWAG

Comment: unfortunately , I do not currently have a scale in my disposal, but their weight is about 4 times the weight of a AA battery , so about 100 g ( I Apologize for the rough calculations but it's all i can do at the moment , I will perhaps weigh these batteries more precisely tomorrow)   .

Comment: Record V, I, t with some load tests between 3.8 and 3.0 both charging and discharging and put into  a spreadsheet. Then you can make graphs like the missing spec sheets  and determine your answer  to capacity but safe current depends on temp and I^2ESR is high with 3.6V/12A=300 mOhms which is about 6x worse than the best around 50 mOhms and typical less than 100 mOhms full charge

Comment: There's probably very little capacity left below 3.2V so I'd be inclined to take that as a max discharge, though 3V should be safe. It'll last longer if you don't use either extreme of its capacity range.

Comment: Yes so limit CV to 4.1V and cutoff at 3.2V under load or 3.4 at rest

Comment: Did you actually short circuit this?  Brave soul!

Comment: @A.H.Z [This article](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/lithium-ion-batteries-call-for-multi-cycle-support-to-maximize-uptime) may help in just generally understanding their charge cycle. I know it is a separate issue. But it is still worth reading once. And [this](https://lygte-info.dk/info/BatteryLowVoltage%20UK.html) also looks interesting with respect to discharge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lowest safe voltage for a lithium cell is around 3.0V irrespective of the capacity.  Below this the cell will be damaged, but for longer life don’t discharge below 3.2V